# Why do I get a Bootstrap JavaScript error in my Chrome Extension?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to create a Chrome extension where I have a button appear on Google's search result page, and onhover over the button, a modal appears.

I can get the modal to begin to appear(background gets dark), but get a JavaScript error before the actual modal box shows.

The error is:

> Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

```
return Element.prototype.querySelector.call(element, selector);
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Button Modal",
    "description": "Button Modal",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "icons": {
        "16": "./icons/icon-16x16.png",
        "36": "./icons/icon-36x36.png",
        "48": "./icons/icon-48x48.png",
        "120": "./icons/icon-120x120.png"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["https://*.google.com/*", "https://google.com/*"],
            "js": ["js/jquery-3.6.1.min.js", "js/bootstrap.bundle.js", "content-script.js"],
            "css": ["css/bootstrap.css", "css/content.css"],
            "run_at": "document_end"
        }
    ],
    "action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_title": "Popup title"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "storage"
    ]
}
```

**content-script.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn-sm").hover(function(){
        $("#exampleModalToggle").modal("show");
    });
});

//add modal after opening body tag
$("body").after("<div id='exampleModalToggle' className='modal fade'><div className='modal-dialog'><div className='modal-content'><div className='modal-header'><h5 className='modal-title'>Modal Title</h5><button type='button' className='close' data-dismiss='modal'>&times;</button></div><div className='modal-body'><p>This is a simple Bootstrap modal. Click the 'Cancel button', 'cross icon' or 'dark gray area' to close or hide the modal.</p></div></div></div></div>");


$("#result-stats nobr").after(" <button type='button' class='btn btn-warning btn-sm'>BUTTON</button>");
```

Comment: What are the argument values there? Why `className` and not `class`?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Bootstrap 5.2.  I wasn't aware of a jQuery conflict with it.  Can you elaborate?  thanks!

Comment: @isherwood - I can't believe I missed that.  Too much React and too little Bootstrap.  I switched it to class for Bootstrap and it seems to work now.  Thank you!

Comment: I see that [jQuery is an option](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/getting-started/javascript/#optionally-using-jquery), but you'd be advised to wean yourself off it. I loved it at one time, but now I try to avoid loading a library that I don't need. See https://youmightnotneedjquery.com.

Answer (score 0):

I had used className in my code instead of class.  This in turn caused the Bootstrap interpreter to throw an error when it came to this code.  Thank you all for your help!